# List opened X Server windows with node-x11 library?

Tags: node.js, x11, xlib

I need to get list of open windows under Linux.

Can i list all open xorg windows using [node-x11](https://github.com/sidorares/node-x11) library?

I try to use xlib for python example for this library but isn't working for it.

```
var x11 = require('../../lib');
x11.createClient(function(err, display) {
   console.log('succesfully connected to \"' + display.vendor + '\" server');
   console.log(display.client.QueryTree());
   display.client.terminate();
});
```

Got error.

```
events.js:72
       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
                  ^
Error: Bad window
    at ReadFixedRequest.callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WindowManager example:

```
var X, x11 = require('../lib');

x11.createClient(function(err, display) {
    X = display.client;
    root = display.screen[0].root;

    X.QueryTree(root, function(err, tree) {
        console.log(tree.children); //output all windows tree
    });
});
```